# how to save a list of web elements with selenium python but when the page is reloading the list continue with the elements?

Tags: python

```
cancel_ancillary = self.context.browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, self.NFF_ANCILIARY_ACTION_BUTTON)
        for index in range(1, len(cancel_ancillary)):
            try:
            

                WebDriverWait(self.context.browser, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.NFF_ACTION_BOTTON)))
                element = cancel_ancillary[index]
                self.context.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
                element.click()
                time.sleep(1)
                WebDriverWait(self.context.browser, 120).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, self.NFF_CANCEL_OPTION))).click()
                alert = self.context.browser.switch_to.alert
                alert.accept()
                try:
                    WebDriverWait(self.context.browser, 30) \
                        .until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, self.NFF_WINDOW_WAIT_AFTER_CANCEL)))

                    WebDriverWait(self.context.browser, 60) \
                        .until_not(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, self.NFF_WINDOW_WAIT_AFTER_CANCEL)))
                except TimeoutException:
                    pass
                WebDriverWait(self.context.browser, 120).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.NFF_ACTION_BOTTON)))
                cancel = self.context.browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@status='Cancelled']")
                cancel_an = cancel[index - 1].text
                assert cancel_an == "Cancelado"
            except Exception as e:
                pass
```

the list dont have elements after the firts iteratinon

Comment: What do you mean the list doesn't have elements after the first iteration?  There's no code here that would remove items from the list.  Do you mean the list only had one element, but you expected it to have more?  Please show us the **actual results** from this code, so we don't have to guess what you meant.

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in question's title.

Comment: when you reload page then it removes for memory all elements from previous page - if you need to go to next page on list then first get all `urls` from elements and later reload page.

Comment: the biggest mistake is `except Exception as e: pass` - you may have some error message but you can't see it. You should at least use `print(e)` instead of `pass`

Comment: what `list` do you mean? Did you use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables?